# React admin 3.x useDataProvider loading indicator

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

In version 2.x when you used the hoc `withDataProvider` and you used the `dataProvider` injected into the props, you could pass some extra options like `onSuccess`, `onFailure` and additionally using that dataProvider made sure all the proper redux actions were called. So you could see the loading indicator and whatnot.

Now with the new hook, you can no longer pass on those options. So you are forced to use also useNotify, useRefresh, etc.
I noticed that also no redux actions are being called.... so no loading indicator.

So basically my question is how to use the `dataProvider` and have it show the loading indicator, but it could be well be paraphrased as have it run all the redux actions that are normally ran when you use the default components like List or View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When migrating from 2.x to 3.x, you have to migrate your custom data provider.
If you had the old kind as specified in 2.x where you used constants:

```
switch() {
  case MY_CUSTOM_ACTION:
}
```

Which was used like this:

```
dataProvider(MY_CUSTOM_ACTION...
```

This old way keeps working, however the redux actions are not dispatched.
Once you migrate into the new way of writing the data provider everything works as expected. https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html#data-providers